# Nested Json in Pandas Column

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a dataframe with nested json as column.

```
df.depth
0     {'buy': [{'quantity': 51, 'price': 2275.85, 'o...
1     {'buy': [{'quantity': 1, 'price': 2275.85, 'or...
2     {'buy': [{'quantity': 1, 'price': 2275.85, 'or..
```

inside each row have 5 depths of buy sell

```
df.depth[0]
{'buy': [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}], 'sell': [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}]}
```

real json structure is as below

```
{'buy': [{'quantity': 51, 'price': 2275.85, 'orders': 2}, {'quantity': 38, 'price': 2275.8, 'orders': 2}, {'quantity': 108, 'price': 2275.75, 'orders': 3}, {'quantity': 120, 'price': 2275.7, 'orders': 2}, {'quantity': 6, 'price': 2275.6, 'orders': 1}], 'sell': [{'quantity': 353, 'price': 2276.95, 'orders': 1}, {'quantity': 29, 'price': 2277.0, 'orders': 2}, {'quantity': 54, 'price': 2277.1, 'orders': 2}, {'quantity': 200, 'price': 2277.2, 'orders': 1}, {'quantity': 4, 'price': 2277.25, 'orders': 1}]}
```

i want to explode this in to something like this

**Required Output**:

```
   depth.buy.quantity1  df.depth.buy.price1 ... depth.sell.quantity1 depth.sell.price1....
0      51                2275.85....                    353          2276
1      1                 2275.85....                    352          2276
```

how to do it ?

Edit:

for help i have added demo dataframe:

```
a={'buy': [{'quantity': 51, 'price': 2275.85, 'orders': 2}, {'quantity': 38, 'price': 2275.8, 'orders': 2}, {'quantity': 108, 'price': 2275.75, 'orders': 3}, {'quantity': 120, 'price': 2275.7, 'orders': 2}, {'quantity': 6, 'price': 2275.6, 'orders': 1}], 'sell': [{'quantity': 353, 'price': 2276.95, 'orders': 1}, {'quantity': 29, 'price': 2277.0, 'orders': 2}, {'quantity': 54, 'price': 2277.1, 'orders': 2}, {'quantity': 200, 'price': 2277.2, 'orders': 1}, {'quantity': 4, 'price': 2277.25, 'orders': 1}]}
c=dict()
c['depth'] = a
df = pd.DataFrame([c,c])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `concat`:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x, index=[0]) for x in i], axis=1) for i in pd.json_normalize(df['depth'])['buy'].tolist()], ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   quantity    price  orders  quantity   price  orders  ...  quantity   price  orders  quantity   price  orders
0        51  2275.85       2        38  2275.8       2  ...       120  2275.7       2         6  2275.6       1
1        51  2275.85       2        38  2275.8       2  ...       120  2275.7       2         6  2275.6       1

[2 rows x 15 columns]
```

Comment: it comes one after another i want in one row

Comment: why it creates 75 columns it should create for buy 5x3 = 15columns

Comment: i have added demo dataframe can u check

Comment: @SurajS Edited my answer pls check it out

Comment: its not working it gives 3 columns but needs 15 buy columns and 15 sell columns with only 2 rows as per demo data given